# Scheduling inside runnable

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, threadpool

I am using Spring ThreadPoolTaskScheduler to execute a task and I am scheduling the same task inside the `run()` method as below. By doing so I am making sure the next is scheduled after the current task is completed.

```
public class Task implements Runnable{
    @Autowired
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler;
    public void run() {
        //some work
        scheduler.schedule(this, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + delay));
    }
}
```

Is this approach safe, will there be any concurrency issues?

Comment: Well, it depends if you have internal state in instances of `Task` objects which could be corrupted if it happens their execution overlap under the assumption that multiple threads can be spawned by the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` can be active at the same time (i.e. it wasn't configured as a single-thread pool).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to hand configure the next execution, you should use `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...)`. It does exactly what your code does, except better.

Comment: I have checked this method before but I thought I have more control in my approach, like I can do something between the completion and next execution dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean?